# Isolation level not working in vb.net connecting to a SQL 2008 DB

Tags: sql, vb.net, isolation-level

I have a VB.net CF app connecting to a SQL 2008 server.
I'm trying to implement transactions but when i break my code at the start of a transaction certain read queries cannot be done on the table.
For instance selecting all records from the table where id <> 123
Won't return any values.
But select * from stock will return all values except for the row I'm working on.

```
Dim SQLComm As Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
Dim myConnString As String = frmConnectionDetails.GetConnectionString
Dim SQLConn As New SqlConnection(myConnString)
Dim SQLTrans As SqlTransaction
SQLConn.Open()
SQLTrans = SQLConn.BeginTransaction(Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
SQLComm = New SqlCommand
SQLComm.Connection = SQLConn
SQLComm.Transaction = SQLTrans
AddOrUpdateStock(objStock, SQLConn, SQLComm)
 -Break here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you start a transaction, the record becomes locked and can't be accessed until either a commit or rollback.  Take a look at this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h.aspx) over at MSDN.

Also, the `Data.IsolationLevel` applies at the connection level.  If you want to do dirty reads you should be using `ReadUncommitted`